# LWC - Get row Id in JS when in row button pressed

Tags: lightning-web-components, table

Wondering if there is and easy way to get a the dynamically generated row id using a button onclick attribute in JS.

```
<template for:each={PS} for:item="partserve">
     <tr key={partserve.Id}>
        <td colspan="5">
           {partserve.Services_Offered__c}
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr key={partserve.Id}>
        <td> {partserve.flatrate}</td>
        <td>{partserve.maxrate}</td>
        <td>{partserve.RateStruc}</td>
        <td colspan="2">
           <button onclick={editButton}>Edit</button>
           <button onclick={deleteButton}>Delete</button>
        </td>
     </tr>      
</template>
```

I've tried event.target in editButton() but am not sure what the syntax would be here to specifically get partServe.Id

Comment: could you please share the structure of partserve list that is generated (sample list atleast)?

Comment: Just objects wrapped in an array, it doesnt really affect the answer to this question as it renders correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use index and assign that as value to the button and in js get all the value at that index like this

```
<template>
<template for:each={PS} for:item="partserve" for:index="index" >
     <tr key={partserve.Id}>
        <td colspan="5">
           {partserve.Services_Offered__c}
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr key={partserve.Id}>
        <td> {partserve.flatrate}</td>
        <td>{partserve.maxrate}</td>
        <td>{partserve.RateStruc}</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <lightning-button label="Neutral"  title="Non-primary action" value={index} onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>

        </td>
     </tr>      
</template>
</template>
```

JS

```
handleClick(event)
{
 console.log(this.PS[event.target.value].Id);
}
```

Comment: I just ended up feeding the {partserve.id} directly into the button value instead of the {index}, saved a step. Great idea! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Bobbygllh maybe you should add the id in your template yourself.

```
<button data-id="editButtonId" onclick={editButton}>Edit</button>

and in .js you can get id using dataset

editButton(event) {

  const editBtnId = event.target.dataset.id;       
}
```

Comment: Syntax didnt work, not sure you mean by adding the id to the template myself